create a scheduled-triggered flow that I can run on demand to update all instances of a custom object the match a criteria
I am attempting to update all instances of a custom object that match a specific criteria (custom object: candidate)
I have tried a bunch of options, but I thought this was close:
Create a Schedule Triggered flow on my object : Candidate

Then , I update the changed records:

When I run this, I get the following error:
Error element update_closed (FlowRecordUpdate).
This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: If you use a record variable to update or delete records, the ID value in the variable must be populated.. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
Result
Failed to update records whose IDs are in {!$Record}.
Error Occurred: If you use a record variable to update or delete records, the ID value in the variable must be populated.
I have searched and googled answers for this with no help, any suggestions?

ok, I finally got this to work another way, here is how I did it, all on the update record:


nice work -- I must have misunderstood your question

The error message is telling you that the record variable has no ID. This is because Candidate__c is not the $Record variable. The quick fix for this is to:

remove the assignment element
change the update element to use the $Record variable rather than the Use the Ids and values from a record variable. $Record contains the triggering Candidate record from the entry condition.

do the assignments here



Hence, your flow is just entry + update

Thank you, I tried this, but have the same error! I will update my question with your suggested approach.
